# VBA Excel - copy, paste loop with offset

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and need some help - if anyone could help me.

I need to copy a range, say A1:F1, and paste it in the row directly under, so A2:F2, on an automatic loop.

The top-most row contains data from a different sheet, therefore I will be copying the formulas of that row which links to the secondary sheet. I would like the loop to end once the other sheet has been exhausted and the macro hits an empty row from the sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: B1 is same row as A1 but one column across.

Comment: This is unclear, you want to copy a table between 2 sheets, with an offset of 1 row under using formulas provided on a second sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do until loop to find the length of your list. Then u can use this index to use range, push down the data and push your new data on the now empty top row.

I understand, that u want to push data always in the first row and everything else down, so you add always one new row.